# glDrawArrays first few calls very slow using my shader and then very fast

Tags: opengl, shader, gpu

I am using my own shader that does quite advanced calculations and outputs results into frame buffer.

I do call glfinish to make sure previous opengl commands are executed on the graphics card. Then i call gldrawarrays and  this single call takes 5 seconds!

After calling gldrawarrays a few more times they finally start running under 1 ms per each call. So only a few first gldrawarrays calls are super slow.

There is no correlation with the size of the textures used, that doesn't affect performance. If i simplify the shader source code it does make the first gldrawarrays calls faster but not dramatically. Sometimes very much benign changes in the shader source code lead to serious changes in performance(e.g. commenting out a few additions or subtractions). But all these code changes can speedup first gldrawarrays calls from 5 seconds to e.g. 1 second, not more. Those changes do not affect much performance of gldrawarrays calls after first few calls are made.Those still run 1ms each, thousand times faster than first 2-3 calls.

I am buffled by this problem. What could possibly be happening here?? Is there a way extract at least some info of what really happening inside that gpu.

Ok, the shader code that affects performance is like this:
    if (aType<18){

```
    if (aType < 9){ 

        if (aType < 6){

            if (aType==2)

            {
                res.x = EndX1;

                res.y = EndY1;

            }

            else

            if (aType==3)
            {
                res.x = EndX2;

                res.y = EndY2;
            }
```

.......... //continues with all these if 36 times

Replacing code above with for loop solved the performance problem:
        for (int i=1; i <= 36; i++){

```
if ((y < EndY[i]) || ((y== EndY[i])&&(x<=EndX[i])))
        {

                res.xy = SubXY(x,y,EndX[i-1],EndY[i-1]);

            res.z= 2;

            return res;
        }
    }
```

Ironically i wanted to avoid for loop for performance reasons :)

Comment: as suggested below i also tried decreasing the output framebuffer size and viewport which had no effect. Also i don't know if it matters i use Linux Ubuntu and gpu is Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Answer (score 2):

Your driver is delaying the serious optimization steps until after the shader has been used a few times. And the non optimized shader may be software emulated.

There are various reasons for this but chiefly is that optimization takes time.

To fix this you can force the shader to run a few time with less data (smaller output buffer by `glViewport`). This will tell the driver to optimize the shaders before you actually need it and it can handle larger loads.

Comment: thank you Ratchet, i tried to decrease framebuffer size and viewport size. This didn't have an effect. Though was a good idea to try.

Comment: Wow, I never heard of this before. Is there a canonical article/page that discusses the details/motivations behind this? It does not seem this method would be friendly on, say, a gaming environment.

Comment: @jim it's common knowledge really that things don't get finalized until they are used (JIT) that's why games will make sure to use shader programs before their usage is time critical

Comment: I program games, using OpenGL, and hadn't experienced this. I could see this kind of thing happening if the backend needed to, somehow, generate shaders on the fly (and thus the compilation could easily cause such a delay, especially on mobile), but I've only experienced that particular example on iOS for Autodesk TinkerBox (and only because we were using OpenGL 1.1; probably we would have been fine if we did 2.0 and thus using our own shaders; and this particular case could have been specific to SGX that needs to patch up shaders for the blend modes).

Comment: Ok, the shader code that affects performance is like this: if (aType<18){

    if (aType < 9){ 

        if (aType < 6){

            if (aType==2)

            {
                res.x = EndX1;

                res.y = EndY1;

            }

            else

            if (aType==3)
            {
                res.x = EndX2;

                res.y = EndY2;
            }

.......... //continues with all these Ifs 36 times

Comment: so my understanding driver understands somehow that there are many Ifs in code and tries to optimize that by letting running it through cpu and not gpu to gather statistics...